# jpg bits per pixel

Tags: image, jpeg

How many bits per pixel in a jpeg. I have a jpg which is  425 x 282 and its size is 20635 bytes. If i encode it to a png its 116255 bytes.

Comment: There is no fixed ratio. I suggest you read up on image compression.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

General answer:

Bits per pixel = Bits/Pixel, 1 Byte = 8 Bits

=> JPG (20635 * 8 bits) / (425 * 282 pixels) => 1,38 bits per pixel

=> PNG (116255 * 8 bits) / (425 * 282 pixels) => 7,76 bits per pixel

But note you're comparing apples to oranges here. [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) is a lossless format, while [JPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) loses quality depending on the compression strength. The bits per pixel value will vary for different images and different quality/compression settings for both formats.

Also, don't mix this with the term "bits per pixel" that is used for the [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) of an image which should be 24 bits per pixel (8 bits for each red, green and blue) in both cases, although PNG supports 8 bits per pixel using a [color palette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_%28computing%29), too (or even 32 bits per pixel using an [alpha channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Transparency_of_image)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about colour depth, I'm tempted to answer "24-bit" and "RGB or CMYK", but the spec appears to be as complicate as all specs are:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

This has little to do with file size, though. JPEG uses a lossy compression algorithm while PNG uses lossless algorithms. That means that a JPEG picture will normally require a larger file if encoded as PNG.