# How to convert a Hex string to a BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, image, hex

I would like to convert Hex string to BufferedImage in Java. 
I can find the BufferedImage to Hex string, but I can't find the way to do the opposite.

Comment: Convert to `byte[]` and then give that to ImageIO to read (probably via ByteArrayInputStream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first convert **hex String** to **byte[ ]** then convert to **buffered image**

```
   String hex = "68656c6c6f";
   byte[] imageInByte= new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray();
```

To convert byte[] to **BufferedImage**

```
    //byte[] imageInByte;
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
 BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Answer (score 2):

This question contains the code to convert a byte array to `BufferedImage`: [Java: BufferedImage to byte array and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414259/java-bufferedimage-to-byte-array-and-back)

Now all you need to do is to convert the hex string to a byte array: [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)