# BufferedImage How to use 1 and 0 to represent white and black colors?

Tags: binary, bufferedimage

I am converting an image to binary image, and use a 1 and a 0 to represent white and black. I only managed to use color array, i.e. white is {255, 255, 255} and black is {0, 0, 0}.
Can anybody help please?
Many thanks.

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414259/java-bufferedimage-to-byte-array-and-back

Comment: Use `new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY)`.