# Convert image in byte and viceversa for socket connection in java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, byte, bufferedimage

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", socket.getInputStream);
```

This is the only way I tried, and it does work but it needs the outputStream to be closed or I can't save the image.

My problem is that I need the connection to be alive even after the sending, so I read on the internet that i have to convert a BufferedImage in byte[] and viceversa in the client and in the server.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why does it need the output stream to be closed to save the image? Are you reading until EOF on the other side of the Socket?

Comment: Because with that command you just read from the InputStream, it doesn't recognize the EOF..

Answer (score 0):

To quote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414259/java-bufferedimage-to-byte-array-and-back) answer here.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte); //convert to buffered image
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: And how do i read from that? I need to convert it back

Comment: @enemy                                                             InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream.flush() and .close() do nothing, but if they didn't you would need to call close() before toByteArray(), and the flush would still be redundant.

Comment: @user3902960 what is "bytes"? could you write the entire code?
I have to read it from another project, so i don't have "bytes" defined. Thank you.