# Java BufferedImage JPG compression without writing to file

Tags: java, image, jpeg, bufferedimage

I've seen [several examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319958/1167783) of making compressed JPG images from Java `BufferedImage` objects by writing to file, but is it possible to perform JPG compression without writing to file? Perhaps by writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414490/1167783)?

```
ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(0.7f);

ImageOutputStream outputStream = createOutputStream();
jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);

// in this example, the JPG is written to file...
// jpgWriter.write(null, outputImage, jpgWriteParam);
// jpgWriter.dispose();

// ...but I want to compress without saving, such as
ByteArrayOutputStream compressed = ???
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just pass your `ByteArrayOutputStream` to `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(...)` like this:

```
// The important part: Create in-memory stream
ByteArrayOutputStream compressed = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try (ImageOutputStream outputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(compressed)) {

    // NOTE: The rest of the code is just a cleaned up version of your code

    // Obtain writer for JPEG format
    ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG").next();

    // Configure JPEG compression: 70% quality
    ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(0.7f);

    // Set your in-memory stream as the output
    jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);

    // Write image as JPEG w/configured settings to the in-memory stream
    // (the IIOImage is just an aggregator object, allowing you to associate
    // thumbnails and metadata to the image, it "does" nothing)
    jpgWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), jpgWriteParam);

    // Dispose the writer to free resources
    jpgWriter.dispose();
}

// Get data for further processing...
byte[] jpegData = compressed.toByteArray();
```

PS: By default, `ImageIO` will use disk caching when creating your `ImageOutputStream`. This may slow down your in-memory stream writing. To disable it, use `ImageIO.setCache(false)` (disables disk caching globally) or explicitly create an `MemoryCacheImageOutputStream` (local), like this:

```
ImageOutputStream outputStream = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(compressed);
```

Comment: Thanks @haraldK! I'm not totally sure what's happening here. If the JPG data is compressed and written to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` named `compressed`, what is the `IIOImage` section doing?

Comment: @JeffThompson I updated the answer for you. The `IIOImage` doesn't "do" anything, it just contains the data you want to write. If you want to learn more, I suggest you read the API documentation or follow a tutorial. :-)

Comment: Thanks again! I did look at the docs, but all the different objects for storing and manipulating file streams is really confusing. This makes way more sense! I did run into errors running out of memory without using the `MemoryCacheImageOutputStream`, FYI.

Comment: How to write a unit test on this method? any suggestion?

Comment: That is question that probably deserves a longer answer than a comment... Ask it (as an SO question)!  
Or you can have a look at the tests in [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) for inspiration, it should contain many tests for code similar to this.