# How can I convert any format of image to compresed WebP byte array in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, image-processing, webp, image-conversion

I'm using below code but this code generate and save image in my localbut I need to convert and process that image into WebP byte Array without saving the image in my local. I'm using 3rd party Library to compress the image.

Library that I used :

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.sejda.imageio</groupId> 
    <artifactId>webp-imageio</artifactId> 
    <version>0.1.6</version> 
</dependency>



public static void main(String[] args) {    

String s = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg";
    
    try {
        URL url = new URL(s.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = url.openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
         
          ImageWriter writer =           ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/webp").next();
         
          WebPWriteParam writeParam = new WebPWriteParam(writer.getLocale());
          
          writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
          //Set lossy compression
          writeParam.setCompressionType(writeParam.getCompressionTypes()              [WebPWriteParam.LOSSY_COMPRESSION]);

          //Set 80% quality.
          writeParam.setCompressionQuality(0.1f);

          // Save the image
          writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(new File("filePath")));

          writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), writeParam);
          
        System.out.println("Complete");
        
        
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So how can I directly get byte array of compressed WebP without saving the file?

Comment: Use `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: This is basically the same Q/A as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726626/1428606, just a different output format (it uses `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

Comment: Maybe `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();writer.setOutput(new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(baos));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String s = 
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg";

        URL url = new URL(s.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = url.openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStrm = null;
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(is);
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", byteOutStrm);
        byte[] orgImgByteArray = byteOutStrm.toByteArray();
        byteInputStrm = new ByteArrayInputStream(orgImgByteArray);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        ImageOutputStream imgOutStrm = null;
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(byteInputStrm);
            ImageWriter writer = 
            ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/webp").next();
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imgOutStrm = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
            writer.setOutput(imgOutStrm);
            WebPWriteParam writeParam = new WebPWriteParam(writer.getLocale());
            writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            writeParam.setCompressionType(writeParam.getCompressionTypes() 
            [WebPWriteParam.LOSSY_COMPRESSION]);
            writeParam.setCompressionQuality(0.4f);   //set compression quality
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), writeParam);
            imgOutStrm.close();
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();//final Answer

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (baos != null) {
                    baos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).